# Display Registration details in Website from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using a website application for registration, in that application i have inserted contols like label boxes and text boxes... And i stored these values in database...

now i have to display the details only without controls in seperate form and the details should take from that database...

How Shall i Do this?

The output should display in next form... the format is

Name:Jessy
RollNo:6315
City:ParkTown

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...the simplest way....

Read the data from database from code behind and use `Response.Write()` to show the data on the page...

Example:

```
            Response.Write("<table border=2>");
            Response.Write("<th>Id</th><th>Name</th>");
            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                Response.Write("<tr>");
                    Response.Write("<td>");
                    Response.Write(row[0].ToString());
                    Response.Write("</td>");
                    Response.Write("<td>");
                    Response.Write(row[1].ToString());
                    Response.Write("</td>");
                Response.Write("</tr>");
            }
            Response.Write("</table>");
```

Comment: i want to display it in a format... it will display arround with some border or display within a table...

Comment: No problem in that too...Please see the code I have included as an example in my answer...

Comment: Great..but be sure that the data coming from the database is safe and valid as you are directly displaying it on the page....

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look to the data access tutorials [page](http://www.asp.net/%28S%28pdfrohu0ajmwt445fanvj2r3%29%29/learn/data-access/).

Answer (score 0):

You should get registration details from database with the help of ADO.net and then u display these details on the separate form.
you can show the data in datagrid also.

This link helps u

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090.aspx

Comment: thanks... but i have to display the details in seperate form without using datagrid

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just want to display that information then you can use Divs or Spans or just labels. Get the information from Database and load that information into label.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Raja

Comment: how to use div to display that details... can you just tell me one example?

Comment: Have a Div Tag in the HTML give an ID and have runat="Server". for ex.
if you add something like <div id="divInfo" runat="server"></div> in your html. Then you can access the Div in the server side like
divInfo.InnerHTML = "Name:"+<put name from db>+" RollNo: " <RollNo> ;